# httpsアクセス時の特定ディレクトリに対するリダイレクト除外

Tags: apache, .htaccess

以下のような条件でリダイレクトを設定したいのですが、うまく行きません。

- *https*でのアクセス時には*http*にリダイレクト
- https://example.com/hoge/ へのアクセス時にはリダイレクトから除外

以下の形でhtaccessを指定しましたが、うまく行きません。

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(hoge)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```

正しい記述方法を教えてください。

Comment: 「うまく行きません」ではなく、「試したパターン」「期待する結果」「実際の結果」を具体的に質問に追記してください。またそのときのログ(取り方はmod_rewriteのドキュメントに書いてあります)を取って質問に追記してください

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http.confでhttps://example.com/ の docroot に対応する定義で「AllowOverride」の設定は .htaccess が有効になるように設定されていますか？
[Apache チュートリアル: .htaccess ファイル](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/ja/howto/htaccess.html)